# How do I create a "rpg door" effect in pygame, and what's wrong with my method?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm creating a game where going near a door(defined using Rect function) calls a function which loads a new game screen which gives the effect of going through to that door inside the house. I tried to do the same thing with the coming out mechanism where I tried to define an area with a Rect object and made it so that when the player comes near it the main game loop is called and it would give the effect of coming out the door but doing so makes it so that the player is stuck in an infinite loop of the screen fading away. the part of the code is attached below and the full code is [here](https://github.com/Batsy24/Pokemon-red.git)

this is the door collision detection

```
    out = pygame.Rect(360, 580, 80, 10)
    player_rect = playerImgXL.get_rect(topleft=(playerXxl, playerYxl))

    if player_rect.colliderect(out):
        game()  # coming out of the house
```

this is the game loop function

```
def game():
  global present_dialogue
  global current_dialogue
  global playerX
  global playerY
  clock.tick(12)
  mixer.music.pause()
  mixer.music.load('pallet_music.mp3')
  # mixer.music.play(100)
  playerX_change = 0
  playerY_change = 0
  running = True
  while running:
      present_dialogue = None
      current_dialogue = None
      for event in pygame.event.get():
          if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
              pygame.quit()
              sys.exit()
      redrawgamewindow()
      pygame.display.update()
```

this isn't the entire game loop there's just the event detection and collision detection between the sys.exit statement and the display update statement

this is the redrawgamewindow function that I call at the end of the game loop

```
def redrawgamewindow():
  global walkcount
  scr.fill((0, 0, 0))
  scr.blit(pallet, (60, 0))
  if current_dialogue:
      scr.blit(*current_dialogue)
      npc_one_dialogue()
  if walkcount + 1 >= 29:
      walkcount = 0
  if up:
      scr.blit(WalkFront[walkcount // 7], (playerX, playerY))
      walkcount += 1
  elif down:
      scr.blit(WalkBack[walkcount // 7], (playerX, playerY))
      walkcount += 1
  elif left:
      scr.blit(WalkLeft[walkcount // 7], (playerX, playerY))
      walkcount += 1
  elif right:
      scr.blit(WalkRight[walkcount // 7], (playerX, playerY))
      walkcount += 1
  else:
      player(playerX, playerY)
  if present_dialogue:
      scr.blit(*present_dialogue)
      npc_two_dialogue()
```

Comment: Best guess - The player is still colliding with the door so the loop repeats. Past that, I need the graphic files to test the game.

Comment: if the player were colliding wouldn't it switch between the two loops? it just runs the screen transition over and over on the same main game loop screen, I also changed the link so that it leads to a GitHub with all the prerequisite files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A few changes are needed to prevent the fade loop:**

- In the `inhouse_oak` function, reset the starting position when the player enters the room
- When the player exits the room, just return to the main game loop

  ```
  def inhouse_oak():
      global playerXxl
      global playerYxl
      playerXxl = 365  # reset starting position
      playerYxl = 480
      ...........
      while running:
          .................
          if player_rect.colliderect(out):
              return  # return to main loop
              # game()  # coming out of the house
  ```
- In the main loop, when the player exits the room, move the player away from the door

  ```
    door3 = pygame.Rect(462, 348, 25, 5)
    if player_rect.colliderect(door3):
        fade(800, 600)
        inhouse_oak()  # Oak's Lab door
        playerY_change = playerX_change = 0  # stop player movement
        playerY += 10  # move away from door
  ```

**To add a fade when exiting the room, make these changes:**

- Generalize the `fade` function.

  ```
  def fade(x, y, rgw):  # last parameter is screen function to call
      fade = pygame.Surface((x, y))
      fade.fill((0, 0, 0))
      for alpha in range(0, 300):
          fade.set_alpha(alpha)
          rgw(True)  # fading = True
          scr.blit(fade, (0, 0))
          pygame.display.update()
  ```
- Add the fading parameter to the main game function.

  ```
  def redrawgamewindow(fading=False):
  ```
- Add the fading parameter to the room function and check the parameter before updating the screen to prevent screen flash.

  ```
  def redrawgamewindow_oak(fading=False):
      .........
      if not fading: pygame.display.update()  # prevent flash if fading
  ```
- Update the fade call in the `redrawgamewindow` function.

  ```
    door3 = pygame.Rect(462, 348, 25, 5)
    if player_rect.colliderect(door3):
        fade(800, 600, redrawgamewindow)  # fade main game
        inhouse_oak()  # Oak's Lab door
        playerY_change = playerX_change = 0
        playerY += 10  #playerX_change
  ```
- In `redrawgamewindow_oak`, when leaving the room, call the `fade` function.

  ```
    if player_rect.colliderect(out):
        fade(800, 600, redrawgamewindow_oak)  # fade room
        return  # return to main loop
        #game()  # coming out of the house
  ```

Comment: oh my god thank you so much! im still new to programming and the stack overflow community has been so helpful I literally cannot thank you enough like I was tryna fix this for a week now

Comment: Save this file to your machine as `diff.htm` then open in a browser: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mjwaddell1/Stuff/main/PokemonPyDiff.htm.  It will show the changes for your script.

Comment: I use WinMerge for file diffs. It has a report feature to export diff results. It's free. https://winmerge.org/?lang=en